# Is there a better dependency injection pattern in golang?

Tags: go, interface

Given this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type datstr string

type Guy interface {
   SomeDumbGuy() string
}

func (d *datstr) SomeDumbGuy() string {
  return "some guy"
}

func someConsumer(g Guy) {
  fmt.Println("Hello, " + g.SomeDumbGuy())
}

func main() {
    var d datstr
    someConsumer(&d)
}
```

Is the wiring of components together that's done in **main** the right way to wire a dependency together?  It seems like I'm over using this a bit in my code.  Is there a common pattern better than this, or am I overthinking it?

Comment: Bit of an opinion-based question, but that's the style I personally prefer.  Unexported struct, exported interface, struct stored by pointer in the interface.  Makes mocking and middleware wrapping super easy, and is better aligned to an object-oriented abstraction principle than exported structs.  Only addition I might make is a factory function for the `datastr` type that returns a `Guy` interface, as this gives a compile-time guarantee that your structure fulfills the interface it is expected to fulfill.

Comment: Google's [Wire](https://github.com/google/wire) looks promising. There're some articles about it: - [Compile-time Dependency Injection With Go Cloud's Wire](https://blog.golang.org/wire) - [Go Dependency Injection with Wire](https://blog.drewolson.org/go-dependency-injection-with-wire)

Comment: https://quii.gitbook.io/learn-go-with-tests/go-fundamentals/dependency-injection

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The best practice is not to use a DI library. Go is meant to be a simple language that is easy to follow. A DI library/framework will abstract that away from you (and to some extent make DI *magical*).

Comment: Unfortunately haven't used wire and neither am i an expert in DI in Golang.  However, i strongly believe that no specific pattern is needed since any library would complicate the program flow and Golang aims to be a language which does not have any *magic* and is easy to follow.

Comment: If this is classed as the best practice, please add a Go doc reference to that effect.  Considering that Google created wire as a DI system that avoids reflection and maintains the calling clarity I find this answer more likely to be incorrect.

Comment: No Go Doc reference; have myself read a bunch of articles and effective go.
Using no DI framework is more idiomatic Go compared to using a DI framework that does reflection or magic under the hood.

Comment: Says who? I've seen quite a few good projects that were using some sort of DI. Also Google with its Wire would argue with your statement...

Comment: Is only I think this DI thing is squalid (by adding a new function variable?) And that why testing looks like shit)

For example, I have a service who do some little logic and send a request to Google Translate API, this service is used by another service, why for the testing parent service need to know all about children service dependencies and insert them into function as params - It confuses me

Comment: Go allows you to make library that does DI. Abstraction is needed to some degree. Just follow DRY and KISS principle. There is no such thing as best practice to not use XYZ libraries. Unless your team abused it. IMHO.

Comment: Anyone coming from an enterprise programming world would not argue that DI should not be used. This is definitely not a best practice, in contrast this is unmaintainable. Any serious server project with more than 5 files would result in manually written wiring code. Using something like Googles Wire makes it much easier. A simple language should not have the goal to stick to a novice level of programmers.

Comment: Still don't know why this answer was selected. It mixed two different things, language specifications, and programming patterns. In essence, it doesn't answer the original question it's just the author's opinion.

Comment: Go's simplicity _as a language_ does not mean it should only be used to write simple _applications_. As an app becomes more complex, a "DI is too complex for Go" mindset will quickly lead to "my Go app's init code is getting hard to maintain", and from there to "my application is too complex for Go" -- at which point you are forced to switch languages.

This _cannot_ be the correct stance; in the long term it will harm the Go community/ecosystem. Dependency injection can be done cleanly, with compile-time safety and without reflection (as in Google's Wire) if that's your preference.

Comment: Wire is trash. Doing it manually costs nothing and is perfectly clear.

Comment: This answer prescribes opinion as best practice.

Comment: Hey - I am new to golang, and I saw this discussion.. I am actually a bit confused about "wire" being considered a DI library. Looking at the tutorial first couple of pages, wire looks like a code generation library that deals with dependency injection. But to me, that is not what I would call DI library. DI Library to me does things at runtime based on configuration sent to it. Am I missing something?

Comment: It is a common misunderstanding that the simplicity of Go means we do not need to use best practices. This is not true, as best practices are always necessary, no matter how simple or complex the language may be.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, the facebookgo inject library allows you to take your injected members and will wire up the graph for you.

Code: https://github.com/facebookgo/inject

Documentation: https://godoc.org/github.com/facebookgo/inject

Here's a code example from the documentation:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/facebookgo/inject"
)

// Our Awesome Application renders a message using two APIs in our fake
// world.
type HomePlanetRenderApp struct {
    // The tags below indicate to the inject library that these fields are
    // eligible for injection. They do not specify any options, and will
    // result in a singleton instance created for each of the APIs.

    NameAPI   *NameAPI   `inject:""`
    PlanetAPI *PlanetAPI `inject:""`
}

func (a *HomePlanetRenderApp) Render(id uint64) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf(
        "%s is from the planet %s.",
        a.NameAPI.Name(id),
        a.PlanetAPI.Planet(id),
    )
}

// Our fake Name API.
type NameAPI struct {
    // Here and below in PlanetAPI we add the tag to an interface value.
    // This value cannot automatically be created (by definition) and
    // hence must be explicitly provided to the graph.

    HTTPTransport http.RoundTripper `inject:""`
}

func (n *NameAPI) Name(id uint64) string {
    // in the real world we would use f.HTTPTransport and fetch the name
    return "Spock"
}

// Our fake Planet API.
type PlanetAPI struct {
    HTTPTransport http.RoundTripper `inject:""`
}

func (p *PlanetAPI) Planet(id uint64) string {
    // in the real world we would use f.HTTPTransport and fetch the planet
    return "Vulcan"
}

func main() {
    // Typically an application will have exactly one object graph, and
    // you will create it and use it within a main function:
    var g inject.Graph

    // We provide our graph two "seed" objects, one our empty
    // HomePlanetRenderApp instance which we're hoping to get filled out,
    // and second our DefaultTransport to satisfy our HTTPTransport
    // dependency. We have to provide the DefaultTransport because the
    // dependency is defined in terms of the http.RoundTripper interface,
    // and since it is an interface the library cannot create an instance
    // for it. Instead it will use the given DefaultTransport to satisfy
    // the dependency since it implements the interface:
    var a HomePlanetRenderApp
    err := g.Provide(
        &inject.Object{Value: &a},
        &inject.Object{Value: http.DefaultTransport},
    )
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // Here the Populate call is creating instances of NameAPI &
    // PlanetAPI, and setting the HTTPTransport on both to the
    // http.DefaultTransport provided above:
    if err := g.Populate(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // There is a shorthand API for the simple case which combines the
    // three calls above is available as inject.Populate:
    //
    //   inject.Populate(&a, http.DefaultTransport)
    //
    // The above API shows the underlying API which also allows the use of
    // named instances for more complex scenarios.

    fmt.Println(a.Render(42))

}
```

Comment: unfortunately the repository `facebookgo/inject` is archived now

Comment: This code illustrates the unnecessary complexity this approach has. uber/dig or google/wire are far better approaches.

Comment: Actually, this was explained far more succinctly than google/wire. It seems like a perfectly legitimate approach to DI. Compile-time DI is not really DI anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You should also try [Dargo](https://godoc.org/github.com/jwells131313/dargo/ioc), which is new but has some features that the facebook one doesn't have.  The code is [here](https://github.com/jwells131313/dargo).

Here is an example:

In this example a service called SimpleService will inject a logger. The logger itself is a dargo service that is bound with a creation method. That creation method looks like this:

```
func newLogger(ioc.ServiceLocator, ioc.Descriptor) (interface{}, error) {
    return logrus.New(), nil
}
```

The binding of SimpleService will provide the struct that should be used to implement the interface. The struct has a field annotated with inject followed by the name of the service to inject. This is the interface and the struct used to implement it:

```
type SimpleService interface {
    // CallMe logs a message to the logger!
    CallMe()
}

// SimpleServiceData is a struct implementing SimpleService
type SimpleServiceData struct {
    Log *logrus.Logger `inject:"LoggerService_Name"`
}

// CallMe implements the SimpleService method
func (ssd *SimpleServiceData) CallMe() {
    ssd.Log.Info("This logger was injected!")
}
```

Both the logger service and the SimpleService are bound into the ServiceLocator. This is normally done near the start of your program:

```
locator, err := ioc.CreateAndBind("InjectionExampleLocator", func(binder ioc.Binder) error {
        // Binds SimpleService by providing the structure
        binder.Bind("SimpleService", SimpleServiceData{})

        // Binds the logger service by providing the creation function 
        binder.BindWithCreator("LoggerService_Name", newLogger).InScope(ioc.PerLookup)

        return nil
    })
```

The returned locator can be used to lookup the SimpleService service. The SimpleService is bound into the Singleton scope (the default scope), which means that it will only be created the first time it is looked up or injected, and never again. The LoggerService, on the other hand is in the PerLookup scope, which means that every time it is injected or looked up a new one will be created.

This is the code that uses the looked up service:

```
raw, err := locator.GetDService("SimpleService")
if err != nil {
    return err
}

ss, ok := raw.(SimpleService)
if !ok {
    return fmt.Errorf("Invalid type for simple service %v", ss)
}

ss.CallMe()
```

Any depth of injection is supported (ServiceA can depend on ServiceB which depends on ServiceC and so on). A service can also depend on as many services as it would like (ServiceA can depend on service D, E and F etc). Howerver, services cannot have circular dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Go 1.18 adds supports for generics, and I think dependency injection can be achieved by using this language feature, it's built into the language now and not an external dependency https://go.dev/blog/intro-generics

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; No. Golang has not been conceived for these patterns.

There is no better dependency injection pattern because Golang (by design) advocates simplicity. For example, there is no class system, but you can build classes with structs, have methods by wiring functions to a struct member, or achieve inheritance by embedding a struct into another. DI is an OOP concept, and Golang is not strictly an OOP language.

"You can't make a silk purse out of a pig's ear."

Answer (score -1):

Your example is super simple with the package here: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/quasi-go/di

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/quasi-go/di"
)

type datstr string

type Guy interface {
    SomeDumbGuy() string
}

func (d *datstr) SomeDumbGuy() string {
    return "some guy"
}

func someConsumer(g Guy) {
    fmt.Println("Hello, " + g.SomeDumbGuy())
}

func main() {
    di.BindType[Guy, datstr]()
    di.Invoke(someConsumer)
}
```