# What is the best way to have dependency injection in Golang

Tags: go, dependency-injection

I'm a beginner in Golang and I'm working on a small library which need to get a DB connection at some point in the code for différent sub package / method call. I'm just wondering how I can manage this ?

Example, If I manage to have a webserver, it works with handler, so how can I get this connection inside this function ?
It could be used with another process, simple method call or MVC model ?

I don't want to use global because for me it's a bad practice except if it's very exceptional way (or tricky somehow).

I read a lot of write in different website, but still, I'm asking and learning from different opinion and experiences.

Thanks for your time !

Comment: There are many good packages out there. But a simple map of factory methods would do too (for many cases, though not all).

Comment: A library, framework, or even map of factories is almost certainly unnecessarily overcomplicating things. Dependency injection just means that if Foo needs a Bar, Foo doesn't create a Bar, Foo receives Bar from whatever is creating/calling Foo.

Comment: @KavehShahbazian Yes I tried to implement a simple one with a map[string]interface{},, but I think I need to practice more to understand some requirements like injector / type..

Comment: @Adrian I agree with you :) But finding a good way / process to inject them will be nice. For now I found a way like creating a Context, storing my instance inside and then giving this context to my struct that need it, but I don't really like this

Comment: In my humble experience `context.Context.Value()` is (at best) a disease. One should avoid it. (IMHO) `context.Context` is the best way to implement a hierarchy of cancellation (combined with `sync.WaitGroup` for confirmation). `context.Context` is immutable in nature which is a good thing. The value part should really be used only inside a request scope (I've never used it for that purpose either).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a better dependency injection pattern in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900053/is-there-a-better-dependency-injection-pattern-in-golang)

Answer (score 3):

Create a struct that represent the resource​, let's call Cart. Add get and post methods to this struct. These methods should be http handlers. In main create an instance of the struct with db interface. And in the route call Cart.get. Now in get method you have access to the db interface.

Not a working example, just to get the idea of injecting for testing.

```
type storage interface {
    PrepareContext(context.Context, string) (*sql.Stmt, error)
}

func main() {
    db, _ := sql.Open("mysql", `queryString`)
    http.HandleFunc("/", Cart{db}.get)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

type Cart struct {
    storage
}

func (crt Cart) get(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    q, _ := crt.PrepareContext(context.Background(), `select *`)
    fmt.Println(q.Exec())
}

/////////Test
type testDB struct{}

func (c testDB) PrepareContext(context.Context, string) (*sql.Stmt, error) {
    return nil, nil
}
func TestGet(t *testing.T) {
    db := testDB{}
    _ = Cart{db}

    //http test here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I still never use a "Context" so I feel lost for now even with  documentation and example.. 
I read this too, it says do not abuse of the Context to store value inside, https://medium.com/@cep21/how-to-correctly-use-context-context-in-go-1-7-8f2c0fafdf39, but as I'm not comfortable with, I think I will use a simple way for now and I will keep practicing with the language :)

Comment: Should be crt.storage.PrepareContext, not crt.PrepareContext

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [Dargo](https://github.com/jwells131313/dargo) which is an injection engine in the style of Java CDI and/or JSR-330.  It uses struct annotations and Injection is performed using reflection or using creator functions.  It supports different lifecycles for services including Singleton (created exactly once, lazily), PerLookup (created every time injected or looked up), Immediate (created exactly once, eagerly) and DargoContext (tied to the lifecycle of a context.Context)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [Hiboot](https://github.com/hidevopsio/hiboot) which is a web/cli application framework that support dependency injection out of box.

[Docs](https://hiboot.hidevops.io/)

```
// HelloService is a simple service interface, with interface, we can mock a fake service in unit test
type HelloService interface {
    SayHello(name string) string
}

type helloServiceImpl struct {
}

func init() {
    // Register Rest Controller through constructor newHelloController
    // Register Service through constructor newHelloService
    app.Register(newHelloController, newHelloService)
}

// please note that the return type name of the constructor HelloService,
// hiboot will instantiate a instance named helloService for dependency injection
func newHelloService() HelloService {
    return &helloServiceImpl{}
}

// SayHello is a service method implementation
func (s *helloServiceImpl) SayHello(name string) string {
    return "Hello" + name
}

// PATH: /login
type helloController struct {
    web.Controller
    helloService HelloService
}

// newHelloController inject helloService through the argument helloService HelloService on constructor
func newHelloController(helloService HelloService) *helloController {
    return &helloController{
        helloService: helloService,
    }
}

// Get /
// The first word of method name is the http method GET
func (c *helloController) Get(name string) string {
    return c.helloService.SayHello(name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest giving a try to https://github.com/facebookgo/inject. It allows to define an object graph and specify dependencies with struct annotations. Injection is performed using reflection.

Comment: Thank you, gonna take a look at this one :)

Answer (score 0):

For an IoC container, you can try this package:
https://github.com/golobby/container

Example of singleton binding:

```
container.Singleton(func() Database {
  return &MySQL{}
})
```

Example of resolving:

```
var db Database
container.Make(&db)
```

As you can see it's so easy to work with.