# Dependency injection with interface in go

Tags: go, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have a struct `StructDependingOnInterface` which depends on `MyInterface` interface. I'd like the struct `Implementation` to be injected into `bar` when `StructDependingOnInterface` is instantiated.

I have tried doing this with facebookgo/inject library, but it seems like it doesn't work with interfaces. `s.bar` is always nil.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/facebookgo/inject"
)

type MyInterface interface {
    Foo()
}

type Implementation struct{}

func (imp *Implementation) Foo() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
}

type StructDependingOnInterface struct {
    bar MyInterface `inject:""`
}

func main() {
    var g inject.Graph

    err := g.Provide(
        &inject.Object{Value: &Implementation{}},
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    g.Populate()

    s := &StructDependingOnInterface{}
    s.bar.Foo()
}
```

Does the language go allows what I'm trying to do ?

Is there an alternative of facebookgo/inject that would fits my need ?

Comment: Create a receiver of StructDependingOnInterface  type on 
Foo implementing interface

Comment: I don't really know what you mean.

Comment: Its like you are using `implementation` struct for `Foo()`. Also you cannot call Foo on nil Pointer as in you did for `s.bar.Foo()` where is s.bar is nil cannot be deference to call `Foo()`. As the error [shows](https://play.golang.org/p/Pt1lXWB7cqt)

Comment: @Greg You need to export `bar` I believe, i.e. changing it to `Bar`... see here: https://github.com/facebookgo/inject/blob/643b7206b487b04fbea325cf6e8d06a66f8db772/inject.go#L239-L240

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a better dependency injection pattern in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900053/is-there-a-better-dependency-injection-pattern-in-golang)

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim I don't think that answers how to do injection when a struct depends on interfaces. The accepted answer of my question is different. But anyway I think it's easier just to buid the objects graph by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[facebookgo/inject](https://godoc.org/github.com/facebookgo/inject) should be able to handle interfaces, look at the example in the link and how they use [`http.RoundTripper`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#RoundTripper) and `http.DefaultTransport`.

First you need to export `bar`, i.e. changing it to `Bar`. Then you also need to pass `s` to `Provide` for `g.Populate` to then be able to set `Bar`.

```
type StructDependingOnInterface struct {
    Bar MyInterface `inject:""`
}

func main() {
    var g inject.Graph

    s := &StructDependingOnInterface{}
    err := g.Provide(
        &inject.Object{Value: s},
        &inject.Object{Value: &Implementation{}},
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := g.Populate(); err != nil {
         log.Fatal(err)
    }

    s.bar.Foo()
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works ! Can we make it work if `Implementation` also has a injectable dependency ?

Comment: I believe so, as long as you export the field and pass an instance of the dependency to `Provide`.

Comment: @Greg also note that if the dependency is a concrete type, as opposed to an interface type, you don't have to pass an instance of it to `Provide` since the library knows what type to instantiate, which is not the case if it's an interface. If you look at the example in their documentation, they don't pass `NameAPI` and `PlanetAPI` to `Provide` as they can infer the types from the fields of `HomePlanetRenderApp`.

Comment: Why is it that inconvenient ? In a clean architecture with 3 layers, controllers, business logic and data access, I have to instantiate the struct of the 2 first layers. I come from a .NET world where I just need to do AddTransient<Interface, Implementation>() and an instance of Implementation will be injected everywhere I use Interface in a constructor. Doesn't Golang allow something like that ?

Comment: @Greg I don't know .NET or any other language/environment/framework that might have a DI comparable to what you have in mind and so I cannot say whether it would, or would not, be possible to implement such a DI in Go so as to alleviate the perceived inconvenience. But, if you're interested, take a look at `go generate`, with that you should be able generate the code that's causing you the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

#### [hiboot](https://github.com/hidevopsio/hiboot) is an cli/web framework that support dependency injection written in Go.

`Code:` https://github.com/hidevopsio/hiboot

Hiboot Overview

- Web MVC (Model-View-Controller).
- Auto Configuration, pre-create instance with properties configs for dependency injection.
- Dependency injection with struct tag name `inject:""` or Constructor func.

Sample Code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/hidevopsio/hiboot/pkg/app/web"
    "github.com/hidevopsio/hiboot/pkg/model"
    "github.com/hidevopsio/hiboot/pkg/starter/jwt"
    "time"
)

// This example shows that token is injected through constructor,
// once you imported "github.com/hidevopsio/hiboot/pkg/starter/jwt",
// token jwt.Token will be injectable.
func main() {
    // create new web application and run it
    web.NewApplication().Run()
}

// PATH: /login
type loginController struct {
    web.Controller

    token jwt.Token
}

type userRequest struct {
    // embedded field model.RequestBody mark that userRequest is request body
    model.RequestBody
    Username string `json:"username" validate:"required"`
    Password string `json:"password" validate:"required"`
}

func init() {
    // Register Rest Controller through constructor newLoginController
    web.RestController(newLoginController)
}

// inject token through the argument token jwt.Token on constructor newLoginController, you may wonder why is token come from
// well, it provided by hiboot starter jwt, see above hiboot link for more details
func newLoginController(token jwt.Token) *loginController {
    return &loginController{
        token: token,
    }
}

// Post /
// The first word of method is the http method POST, the rest is the context mapping
func (c *loginController) Post(request *userRequest) (response model.Response, err error) {
    jwtToken, _ := c.token.Generate(jwt.Map{
        "username": request.Username,
        "password": request.Password,
    }, 30, time.Minute)

    response = new(model.BaseResponse)
    response.SetData(jwtToken)

    return
}
```