# How to implement dependency injection for a database in Golang using interfaces

Tags: go, dependency-injection, interface

I have the following code which tries to implement dependency injection with the database so I can mock it later in the tests.

The problem is that the compiler doesn't recognize db as implementing the interface:
`cannot use db (type *sqlx.DB) as type storage in field value: *sqlx.DB does not implement storage`.

```
package main

func main() {
    db, _ := database.NewDB()

    api, _ := controllers.NewAPI(db)
    api.Register(data)
}
```

controllers/main.go

```
package controllers

type storage interface {
    AccountExists(id int64)
}

type API struct {
    storage
}

func NewAPI(db *sqlx.DB) (*API, error) {
    return &API{db}, nil
}

func (api *API) Register(userdata) {
    // register user here
}
```

storage/database.go

```
package database

func NewDB() (*sqlx.DB, error) {
    // connect to db ere
    return database, nil
}

type DB struct {
    *sqlx.DB
}

func (db *DB) Account(id int64) (bool, error) {
    // query db here
}
```

I've tried implementing the type `DB` in `controllers`, but if I don't declare it in `database` I cannot define its methods there, and if I declare it in both, the compiler won't recognize it as implementing the interface. I think I'm close to implement this but I've really tried all I can think of.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a better dependency injection pattern in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900053/is-there-a-better-dependency-injection-pattern-in-golang)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track, but there are some bugs in your interface-related code.

In order for a struct to implement your `storage` interface it needs to have a method with the signature `AccountExists(id int64)`. According to the spec (https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#DB) `sqlx.Db` does not have a method with this signature.

What you need to do is something like this:

```
package database

func NewMyDB() (*MyDB, error) {
    dbConnection := // get an *sqlx.DB instance
    return &MyDB{db: dbConnection}, nil
}

type MyDB struct {
    db *sqlx.DB
}

func (db *MyDB) AccountExists(id int64) {
    // query db here
}
```

Controllers:

```
type storage interface {
    AccountExists(id int64)
}

type API struct {
    db storage
}

func NewAPI(db storage) (*API, error) {
    return &API{db}, nil
}
```

Note a couple things. 1. previously your `NewMyDB` constructor was returning an instance of `sqlx.DB` rather than an instance of your struct (which I renamed to `MyDB` to avoid confusion with the `sqlx.DB` class). 2. previously your `MyDB` struct did not have a method with the signature  `AccountExists(id int64)`. Thus it did not implement `storage` because `storage` requires this method.

I suggest reading up a bit on how interfaces work in Golang. I think that will help a lot with solving your issues here. Here's a link you can check for a quick read (which includes another link to a longer, but useful, blog post): https://gobyexample.com/interfaces

Comment: Thanks. One of the hints that also helped me a lot was `func NewAPI(db storage)`. it didn't occur to me to use the type storage in the parameters, for some reason.